# Delphi DX Seattle FMX - Datasnap Sample - ExecProc - [Value] overflow error

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, datasnap, delphi-10-seattle

I'm running Delphi DX Seattle
 
and I was having a look at the data-snap sample

Samples\Object Pascal\DataSnap\FireDAC\SampleDataSnapFireDAC_ProjectGroup.groupproj

I'm not worried about actually reversing a string, just wondering why the data snap call was getting the error below

[image]

These are the steps i can reproduce the error with
Step 1: Start the Server
Step 2: Start the Client
Step 3: Click the reverse string button and type "Test".  works fine
Step 4: Click the reverse button again and type "testtest". it fails with this error

> Error
>   [FireDAC][Stan]-704. Variable length data parameter [Value] overflow. Value length - [8], parameter data maximum length - [4].

I can change step 3 and 4 e.g.
Step 1: Start the Server
Step 2: Start the Client
Step 3: Click the reverse string button and type "123456789".  works 
Step 4: Click the reverse button again and type "123".works 
Step 5: Click the reverse button again and type "123456789abcd".fails

It seems to break after the first call, if the string is larger than the first call.
This is the code that the sample was executing

```
procedure TClientForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  AString: string;
begin
  AString := InputBox('Reverse String', 'Enter a String', '');
  if AString <> '' then
  begin
    FDStoredProcReverse.Params[0].Value := AString;
    FDStoredProcReverse.ExecProc;
    ShowMessage(FDStoredProcReverse.Params[1].AsWideString);
  end;
end;
```

Is there a better way to do this?
does anyone else get this error?

Comment: If you just want a function to reverse a string, use [StrUtils.ReverseString](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StrUtils.ReverseString).

Comment: Perhaps I got it wrong - it is my understanding that the question is not how to reverse a string but rather how to call a DataSnap method.

Comment: yea i was just playing with the datasnap stuff - one of the calls was to reverse a string. do you get the same error when using the FMX Datasnap sample

Comment: Works fine for me.  Check your parameter in FDStoredProcReverse and see if Size property has accidentally been set to 4

Comment: did you click the button twice and make the second string bigger than the first string?

Comment: e.g. test then testtest fails but test then tes works. or if you restart the client 123456789 works then 1234567890 fails